# Unidentified whitespace character in Java

Tags: java, whitespace

On extracting some html from a web page, I have some elements containing text that end in an unknown or non-matching whitespace character (ie does not match "\\s"):

```
<span>Monday </span>
```

In java, to check what this character is, I am doing:

```
String s = getTheSpanContent();
char c = s.charAt(s.length() -1);
int i = (int) c;
```

and the value of i is: 160

Anyone know what this is? And how I can match for it?

Thanks

Comment: Match for it how? Do you need the regex or were you going to use another method.  Also, what are you trying to accomplish by matching it? We can give better answers with more information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a [non-breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). According to the [`Pattern` Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), `\\s` matches `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`, so you'll have to explicitly add `\xA0` to your regex if you want to match it.

Comment: ok, thanks - this ties with the html source. Joel's solution below also works.

Comment: so my regex for matching all whitespace inc. non-breaking is: "[\\s\\xA0]+" - appears to work. cheers for help.

Answer (score 4):

That's [`\u00A0`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), also known as *non-breaking space*. If you know HTML, you'll understand that it's the same space as represented by `&nbsp;`. Apparently one was using it instead of a normal space.

Comment: ok that makes sense. I can see in the source &nbsp; - but my parser was converting it to this character that didn't match \\s. cheers

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you were looking for a regex pattern to match the particular character. Anyway, it's good to know that decimal 160 equals to hex A0 so that you after all know which hexcode to use in regex and unicode charts :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using this to match whitespace

```
Character.isSpaceChar(c) || c <= ' ';
```

Answer (score 4):

I made this spreadsheet once to show you some of the different definitions of whitespace used in Java.  It's pretty fascinating (if you're weird like me).

http://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pd8dAQyHbdewRsnE5x5GzKQ

Incidentally, Guava's CharMatcher.WHITESPACE tracks the latest Unicode 5.x standard, and is thus often a better choice than JDK methods.

http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com

Comment: The first link doesn't work anymore: The page does not exit.

Comment: just a note: the class CharMatcher is annotated with @Beta (v17.0)